# Allow folder creation in root from within running Docker container

Tags: docker

In Jenkins I'm using the following image: `ghcr.io/terraform-linters/tflint-bundle`.

When initializing TFLint it tries to create a directory under root:

```
[DEBUG] Mkdir plugin dir: /root/.tflint.d/plugins/github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-aws/0.10.1
```

I run into a permission denied error as I'm not allowed to create the folder. Any idea of what kind of args I can pass along to allow this creation?

Comment: Can you provide some details of the Dockerfile, compose, or docker run command?

Comment: Jenkins Docker plugin. I'm able to bypass with root privileges, but I want to avoid passing the -u root

```groovy
    docker {
      image 'ghcr.io/terraform-linters/tflint-bundle'
      args '-u root:root --entrypoint=\'\''
    }
```

Please ignore the ugly formatting, comments don't really allow me to format it.